# observeOn() impacts doOnTerminate() invocation

Tags: android, rx-java

I have the following code

```
Observable.just(10)
            .doOnTerminate(() -> Log.d("LOG", "ON TERMINATE"))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result -> {
                int a = result / 0; // force an exception
            }, error -> {
                Log.d("LOG", "ERROR");
                error.printStackTrace();
            });
```

Which will give output:

LOG: ON TERMINATE

LOG: ERROR

But If I modified it a bit into

```
Observable.just(10)
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
             .doOnTerminate(() -> Log.d("LOG", "ON TERMINATE"))
             .subscribe(result -> {
                 int a = result / 0; // force an exception
             }, error -> {
                 Log.d("LOG", "ERROR");
                 error.printStackTrace();
             });
```

It will only gives
LOG: ERROR

Why is the `doOnTerminate` function did not get called on the second code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is because of where the doOnTerminate should be called. In first case it is called on the new thread. So events are as follows:

```
+-newThread-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| emission      ----- 10 -- |(completion because only one item was emitted)         |
| doOnTerminate            call(reason for calling is that emissions completed)     |
+-mainThread------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| subscriber    ----- 10(throw div/0)---X                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you look into how [`just` operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/v2.0.4/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableScalarXMap.java#L244) is implemented under the hood you will see that it calls `onCompleted` right after `onNext`.

And when you move the doOnTerminate to the main

```
+-newThread-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| emission      ----- 10 -- |(completion because only one item was emitted)         |
+-mainThread------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| doOnTerminate                                                        (not called) |
| subscriber    ----- 10(throw div/0)->X                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Reason for not calling the `doOnTerminate` is that the error happened in the onNext portion of the subscriber. And in this case it is the [LambdaObserver](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/v2.0.4/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/observers/LambdaObserver.java) which when detects the error in [`onNext`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/v2.0.4/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/observers/LambdaObserver.java#L56) calls `onError` directly(see the link).

---

My test code:

```
    final long[] start = {0};
    Observable.just(10)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext(integer -> {
                start[0] = System.currentTimeMillis();
                message("onNext", start[0]);
            })
            .doOnTerminate(() -> message("doOnTerminate", start[0]))
            .doFinally(() -> message("doFinally", start[0]))
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> message("doAfterTerminate", start[0]))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnTerminate(() -> message("doOnTerminate", start[0]))
            .doFinally(() -> message("doFinally", start[0]))
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> message("doAfterTerminate", start[0]))
            .subscribe(integer -> {
                        message("Next", start[0]);
                        int a = integer / 0;
                    },
                    throwable -> message("ERROR", start[0])
            );

     void message(String message, long start) {
            Log.d("LOG", message + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
     }
```

And it's output:

```
D/LOG: onNext RxNewThreadScheduler-1 0
D/LOG: doOnTerminate RxNewThreadScheduler-1 0
D/LOG: doAfterTerminate RxNewThreadScheduler-1 0
D/LOG: doFinally RxNewThreadScheduler-1 0
D/LOG: Next main 16
D/LOG: doFinally main 16
D/LOG: ERROR main 16
```

---

**Solution**

To be safe from this case and in the same time from missing unsubscription(disposal) event I would use the doFinally operator.

*All this is based on the 2.0.4 version of RxJava.*

Comment: Thanks. I tried using `finallyDo` after `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` but it doesn't get invoked. I think that because I'm using RxJava 1.1.0 and the implementation has changed in RxJava 2

Answer (score 0):

`doOnTerminate` will *NOT* be called on unsubscription, only on `onError` or `onComplete`. As your error occurs *after* the operator, only unsubscribe will reach it.

Add `.doOnUnsubscribe(() -> Log.d("LOG", "ON TERMINATE"))` after the `doOnTerminate`.